# How to fix 'Cannot convert input to Timestamp' ARIMA.predict

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

I need to check ARIMA model by checking its r2 score. So i need to do ARIMA.predict, but here is an error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-10 06:00:00', '2014-05-05 16:00:00',
>                 '2014-04-28 20:00:00', '2014-03-27 21:00:00',
>                 '2012-08-26 09:00:00', '2012-09-29 08:00:00',
>                 '2013-02-15 03:00:00', '2013-02-28 09:00:00',
>                 '2014-06-27 06:00:00', '2014-01-18 11:00:00',
>                 ...
>                 '2013-11-10 22:00:00', '2013-03-18 21:00:00',
>                 '2013-09-09 00:00:00', '2013-06-08 21:00:00',
>                 '2013-11-11 12:00:00', '2014-07-07 05:00:00',
>                 '2014-07-27 12:00:00', '2014-06-03 23:00:00',
>                 '2012-09-20 12:00:00', '2012-12-18 22:00:00'],
>                dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datetime', length=3658, >freq=None)] of type  to >Timestamp

Here is my code:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
train=pd.read_csv("D:/Coding/Datasets/train_traffic.csv", parse_dates= 
['Datetime'], index_col='Datetime',date_parser=dateparse)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ms.train_test_split(train.index, 
train.Count, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)

model = ARIMA(ts_log, order=(2, 1, 0), freq='H')  
AR = model.fit(disp=-1)
AR.predict(X_test)
```

Data example and types: In Excel: 25-08-2012 00:00.

pd.read_csv without parametrs:

```
Out:dtype('O') 
Out:'25-08-2012 00:00'
```

with parametrs:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
pd.read_csv("D:/Coding/Datasets/train_traffic.csv", parse_dates=['Datetime'], index_col='Datetime',date_parser=dateparse)

Out:dtype('<M8[ns]')
df.index[0]
Out:Timestamp('2012-08-25 00:00:00')
```

also i tried

```
pd.read_csv("D:/Coding/Datasets/train_traffic.csv", index_col='Datetime').index[0]

Out:'25-08-2012 00:00'
Out:dtype('O')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand the question and where is exactly the problem but I'll do my best to give you a reproductible code.

For this example, I used the [Daily total female births in California dataset](https://datamarket.com/data/set/235k/daily-total-female-births-in-california-1959#!ds=235k&display=line).

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

df = pd.read_csv("daily-total-female-births-in-cal.csv", nrows = 365)
df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)

train = df.iloc[0:300, :]
test = df.iloc[300:, :]

arima = ARIMA(train, order = (1,1,0), freq = 'D').fit(disp = 0)
prediction = arima.predict(test.index[0], test.index[-1], dynamic = True)
```

You should not use train_test_split() from sklearn with a time series problem. You should use TimeSeriesSplit also from sklearn.

Comment: so you imported from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit but where did you use it here ?